# Is it possible to have a combination of horizontal and vertical CRSs with different distance unit systems?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, map-unit

For example, please consider a combination of EPSG:6360 (NAVD88 height (**ftUS**)) as vertical CS and EPSG:6596 (NAD83(2011) / Washington North(**metre**)) as horizontal CS.

These two CRSs have different distance unit: **meters** and **feet**.

- Is such a combination allowed to exist in the rules?
- Are there usage scenarios that require such a combination?
- If there is a usage scenario, what distance unit should be adopted to measure the 3D distance?

Comment: All air chart elevations are in feet, but the underlying map can be in metres (WGS84/UTM). This is because altimeters read in feet. I have worked with LAS files where the elevation is in metres but the XY CRS is geographic. In both of these cases 3d measurement would be illogical.

Answer (score 2):

Such combination is called as "Combined reference system" https://www.crs-geo.eu/definition-crs.htm.

> The horizontal and vertical components of the description of a
> position in the space may sometimes come from different Coordinate
> Reference Systems. This shall be handled by a compound Coordinate
> Reference System (CCRS). The compound Coordinate Reference System
> describes the position by two independent Coordinate Reference
> Systems. An European spatial reference system could be described as a
> compound Coordinate Reference System. An example is shown in the
> figure.

Some compound CRSs have EPSG code, for example https://epsg.org/crs_9290/ETRS89-MSL-NL-depth.html?.

Proj library supports a custom abbreviated syntax for expressing a compound CRS "EPSG:2393+5717" https://proj.org/development/reference/functions.html#c.proj_create.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response, it is much appreciated.
Just this time in particular I am concerned about the case where the units of distance are different in horizontal and vertical CRS.

Comment: The ETRS89 + MSL NL depth case is such. Horizontal CRS has degrees as units, vertical CRS is using meters.